# Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I want regex to match Google.com to apple.com YouTube.com but not admin.google.com payment.apple.com admingoogle.com student.google.admin.co.in etc

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: What about `www.google.com` or `https://www.google.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a word boundary (`\b`) to indicate that you want the start of the match to be at a word boundary, for example:

```
/\b(?:google|apple|youtube).com\b/gi
```

However, this will still match with a `.` so you can use a negative look-behind to ignore those -

```
/\b(?<!\.)(?:google|apple|youtube).com\b/gi
```

Notice the `gi` at the end - you need the `i` to make it case insensitive.

If you don't want to make it all case insensitive, you can turn this on at particular points with `(?i)`:

```
/\b(?<!\.)(?i)(?:google|apple|youtube).com\b/g
```

You can see this working at https://regex101.com/r/2vc3uH/1

With regex101 you can play around with some regex and if you look on the right of the window, you can learn about what each part of the pattern is doing. There's also a small document reference at the bottom right which can help you write your own patterns.

Comment: But it doesn't matches google.co.in also fonts-akamai.com should not match it matches with akamai.com